# Do not hide specific childnodes onclick a parent

Tags: jquery, html, hide, parent

I've got the next HTML code:

```
<div id="main-container">
  <article id="doyou">...</article>
  <article id="theydid">...</article>
  <article id="nieuws">...</article>
  ...
</div>
```

I'm trying to hide the articles when clicked on the div outside the articles, but not when the articles itself are clicked. Currently I got the following code, but it ain't working:

code:

```
$("#main-container").click(function(){
        $('article#doyou').not(this).hide();
        $('article#theydid').not(this).hide();
        $('article#nieuws').not(this).hide();
        $('article#stage').not(this).hide();
        $('article#info').not(this).hide();
        $('article#contact').not(this).hide();
        $('article#letop').not(this).hide();
    });
```

Comment: If you are hiding divs that are not being clicked on, how can they be made visible again?

Comment: by adding a button of link within the code : $('article#doyou').show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd give each article a common class:

```
<div id="main-container">
    <article id="doyou" class="article">...</article>
    <article id="theydid" class="article">...</article>
    <article id="nieuws" class="article">...</article>
    ... other articles ...
</div>
```

Then in jQuery you can use that class to hide all except the clicked element:

```
$(function() {
    $(".article").click(function() {
        hideArticles();
        $(this).show();
    });

    $("#main-container").click(function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == "main-container")
            hideArticles();
    });
});

function hideArticles() {
    $(".article").hide();
}
```

As I mentioned in my comment though, there is no mechanism for displaying all the articles again. Once an article has been clicked, all others will not be recoverable.

You may want to add a 'show articles' button:

```
$("#show-articles").click(function() {
    $(".article").show();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I think i wasn't clear enough: The DIV#main-container (parent of the articles) has to be clicked to hide all of the articles. But if a specific article has been clicked, the article needs to stay visible.

Comment: No problem, I've edited my post to include that functionality.

Comment: Hmm still doesn't work, because of the "main-container - hide function" overrules the article function. Check my test: http://tinyurl.com/3exv3ro

Comment: Edited again, included a check on the event target when hiding the articles.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main-container").click(function(e) {
        $('article#doyou').not(e.target).hide();
        $('article#theydid').not(e.target).hide();
        $('article#nieuws').not(e.target).hide();
        $('article#stage').not(e.target).hide();
        $('article#info').not(e.target).hide();
        $('article#contact').not(e.target).hide();
        $('article#letop').not(e.target).hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/5uuLc/1/